# Nth of matched elements CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to select the nth of the **matched elements** in pure CSS? Similarly to `$(selector)[Nth]`

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The css rule `div ul li` will select all li elements, now I only want to manipulate the first.

`div ul li:nth-of-type(1)` will select three elements
 `div li:nth-of-type(1)` doesn't work either, since it means "first `li` of the parent"

This is just an example, the tree may be much deeper and have an irregular structure. Out of my matched elements, I want to select the nth. Is there a way to do that? Either to select a specific index, or a range?

Comment: Which elements are you actually trying to match here? It's possible to do something like ul:nth-of-type(n) then within that rule select an li using an nth rule?

Comment: use :nth-child(n)/first-child/last-child

Comment: @thecraighammond I have a css rule that match a number of elements, `li ul li` out of those I only want to select the nth element. Similar to `$(selector)[N]`.

Comment: @TMDinesh What do you mean? `first-child` is just short for `nth-child(1)`

Comment: you need more details about nth-child just view this link http://nthmaster.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this structure

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You would need

```
div ul:first-of-type li:first-child
```

or

```
div ul:first-of-type li:nth-child(1)
```

> Is there a way to select the nth of the matched elements in pure CSS?

**No.** No such CSS Selector exists

**To select the nth `li` in an unknown structure such as this you need javascript**

```
var n = 4
// where n = the 4th one required 

$( "li" ).eq( n-1 ).css( "color", "red" );
```

```js
var n = 4
  // where n = the 4th one required 

$("li").eq(n - 1).css("color", "red");
```

```css
li {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[Jquery Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qcve4xzm/)

Comment: What about the Nth, if I don't know what `ul` the `li` is in?

Comment: You said you wanted the first one. Other than that you need Javascript.

Comment: @user1506145 Your question started off with one very good question (which cannot be done using CSS like Paulie_D has mentioned) and then with your example you completely changed it to a different one (which can be done with CSS) and that's the reason why you are seeing answers that probably don't match your real need. You seem to be looking for the [`nth-match`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo) selector which is currently not implemented.

Comment: @Harry In order to make an example it is hard to make a completely generic one.

Comment: @Paulie_D It was just an example, I want the Nth one, as the title and question suggest

Comment: Updated answer...you need javascript.

Comment: @user1506145 I do understand that but the point of your question got completely changed by that example. You could have easily said I want to select the 4th or 5th `li` and there would have been different answers. Nevermind though, I was just trying to reason.

Comment: @Paulie_D I can not use javascript, need to do it in pure CSS, as I wrote in the question :)

Comment: Then it **cannot** be done...no such selector exists in CSS

Comment: @Harry then people would just have been saying `ul:nth-of-type(2) -> li:nth-of-type(2)` or something like that

Answer (score -1):

you can use the `:first-child` pseudo class

```
li:first-child {

}
```